# How to access server through custom domain?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cname

I created a Node.JS server in Bluemix and everything runs fine. But I can only access it through the given Bluemix domains.

I tried to configure the CNAME on my domain provider [TransIP](https://www.transip.nl) but it doesn't work. And I also couldn't find a lot of documentation about it.

Can you point me to the right place or tell me how to do it?

Comment: what did you configure in your CNAME? are you trying to access your app using http or https?